# Beginner: ASP.NET Web API: How to set apicontroller.user?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2

Given an url like

```
https://name:password@host/something
```

, how do I get the apicontroller object to use "name" as username?
I've looked everywhere and there are lots of postings how to do complicated things in complicated ways but what's the simplest way of doing this?
Can I just derive from AuthorizeAtteibute and set it somewhere in there?

So far no authentication at all is configured.

Lots of Greetings!
Volker

Comment: Are you using Basic Authentication or Forms Authentication?

Comment: Right now I'm using none at all.

Comment: If you plan to  use Basic Authentication then you can create a HttpModule by implementing IHttpModule interface. Have a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication. I doubt you would be able to do this using AuthorizeAttribute

Comment: Ok, so for now it's basic authentication. NExt, I'll need to figure out how to configure this. But this is another question. Right now, I'd happily mark your resposes as answer but comments can't be marked as such.

Comment: I have moved my comment to answer section. I have also provided a link which will guide you in setting up basic authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use Basic Authentication then you can create a HttpModule by implementing IHttpModule interface. Have a look at [Basic Authentication](http://asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication). I doubt you would be able to do this using AuthorizeAttribute

Configuring Basic Authentication on IIS is fairly simply. You can do it using IIS Manager (inetmgr). Check out [Configure Basic Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)